# Apply CSS to a group of css classes containing col- substring

Tags: css, css-selectors

I wasn't sure of the best way to word this and that's probably why I have struggled to research it even though it is probably simple.

What I want to do is a apply CSS to a group of classes.

For example I have the classes  `.col-1`,  `.col-2`,  `.col-3`,  `.col-4`

What I want to be able to do is make some css that can say maybe change the border color for all classes with the text `col-` so I don't have to apply it to each individual number.

I'm sure I've seen this before but cannot think how to do it.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You could use `[class*="col-"]` [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select any element contains at least one occurrence of `col-` as its `class` value.

```css
[class*="col-"] {
    border-color: red;
}
```

If all values of `class` attributes begin with `col-`, you could use `[class^="col-"]` selector.

However, in order to prevent for classes like `foo-col-1` to be selected, you could use a combination of two above selectors as follows *(Thanks to [@JosephSpens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509402/apply-css-to-a-group-of-other-css-classes/22509502#comment34247683_22509502))*:

```css
[class^="col-"], [class*=" col-"] {
  border-color: red;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wowexaji/1/edit)**.

Comment: `[class^=col-]` may be more appropriate if they all start with col (not terribly clear from the Q though)

Comment: To avoid styling unintended classes like `.span-col-1`, you could do `[class^="col-"], [class*=" col-"]`.

Comment: Responding to that last edit you made about if values of `class` begin with the selector... it's bad practice to assume any given class is going to be the first one in the classlist of an element.

Comment: Yes that is the one I was looking for!

Comment: This is very useful. Can I confirm that I can differentiate between <tbody> and <tbody id="titlxxxx"> by using [id^=titl] ? It seems to work fine but just want to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

CSS [attribute*=value] selector

```
<style>
div[class*=col-]{
color: green;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="col-4">
<p>this is an example one</p>
<div>
<div class="test">
<p>this is an example one</p>
<div>
<div class="col-8">
<p>this is an example three</p>
<div>
</body>
```

Please check below link

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_attr_contain